# JMeter - JSON path regex issue

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

Please help me to investigate why there is an error with JSON path expression while everything ok with the same expresssion on "jsconquerytool" website.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0qpA.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk2OT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression in JMeter misses dot:

- In jsonquerytool you have:

  ```
  $.attachments[?(@.name="attachment for delete")].id
  ```
- in JMeter you have

  ```
  $.attachments[?(@name='attachment for delete')].id
                   ^ here the dot is missing
  ```

So given you correct this typo everything should start working as expected.

References, just in case:

- [Jayway - JSONPath - Operators](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#operators)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)